# Dynamodb sparse indexes implementation

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am new to dynamodb, and I came across [sparse indexes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes-general-sparse-indexes.html#bp-indexes-sparse-examples). I think they fit for what I need, but I am not completely sure how to implement them. In my case I have a table with a **Post** entity that has the following fields, it looks like this:

```
post_id <string> | user_id <string> | tags <string[]> | public <boolean>| other post data attributes...
```

The queries that I need to do are:

1. Get all posts that are marked public
2. Get posts filtered by tags
3. Get all posts filtered by user, both public and not public
4. Get a single post

For case of getting all public posts I think **sparse indexes** could work. I could set the public attribute only to the entities that are marked with public. But, how does a query look like then?

I am not even sure if I have set up the DB correctly. I am using serverless framework and this is what I have come up, but not sure if that is good.

```
PostsDynamoDBTable:
      Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          - AttributeName: postId
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: userId
            AttributeType: S
          - AttributeName: createdAt
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: postId
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: userId
            KeyType: RANGE
        BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
        TableName: ${self:provider.environment.POSTS_TABLE}
        GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
          - IndexName: ${self:provider.environment.USER_ID_INDEX}
            KeySchema:
              - AttributeName: userId
                KeyType: HASH
              - AttributeName: public
                KeyType: RANGE
            Projection:
              ProjectionType: ALL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sparse index could work *if you only want a subset of attributes*, you'd want to use `ProjectionType: INCLUDES` to include the non-key attributes into the sparse index (in your case: public attributes). It's important to note that the only attributes you can access in a query to a sparse index are the attributes you explicitly include.

Firstly, you'd need to declare those public attributes in your Attribute Definitions.

Say for example, one of the public attributes is `userName`.
You'd want to add:

```
 - AttributeName: userName
   AttributeType: S
```

Then, in the `GlobalSecondaryIndexes` block:

```
GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
  - IndexName: byUserIdAndPublic // You can name this whatever you'd like
    KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: userId
        KeyType: HASH
      - AttributeName: public
        KeyType: RANGE
      Projection:
        NonKeyAttributes:
        - userName
      ProjectionType: INCLUDE
```

Then you simply query that index specifically - in the response, you'll get back the userName (no special query changes are required, except to specify using this index).

If you need *all* attributes for each post, you'd want to use `ProjectionType: ALL`, (and then just remove the `NonKeyAttributes` bit)

Here's an example nodejs method that would filter posts by public (public being a boolean passed into the method):

```
const listByUserIdAndPublic = async (userId, public) => {
  const params = {
    TableName: tableName,
    IndexName: 'byUserIdAndPublic',
    KeyConditionExpression: '#public = :public AND #userId = :userId',
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      '#userId': 'userId',
      '#public': 'public'
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ':public': public,
      ':userId': userId
    },
  };
  const response = await documentClient.query(params).promise();
  return response.Items;
};
```

Based on your question:

> Get all posts that are marked public

I think you'd want to use a full index (`ProjectionType: ALL`), because I'd imagine you want all attributes of a post to be indexed.

Comment: It might be that I made myself misunderstood. The public field was suppose to be a boolean, it would be at least in a relational DB, that would serve as a filter to only fetch entities that have public set to true. I am not sure that is the same to what you are suggesting in your answer.

Comment: Ah - I did misunderstand you.

I thought you were asking for a way to index all public posts (public in my example is indeed a boolean), and then also fetch only the attributes which are considered "public" (in my example: userName).

I will amend my answer with the query

Comment: Okay, I've added an example query. The index stores all posts - but lets you query them by public = true or public = false.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Is it possible to make a query on a table like that where I would also check for example  if a post contains a tag: ```KeyConditionExpression: '#public = :public AND #userId = :userId AND #tag CONTAINS tag'``` Do I need to make another key for tag?

Comment: After reading upon more about my use case, I guess the composite sort key is what I need. I am not sure how to define composite sort keys with serverless framework I will make another question for it. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Oh I can help you with that as well. Shoot me your question, or perhaps reach out to me on twitter and I can help!

Comment: Thanks, since I don't have a twitter account I will give you the SO link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64356291/setting-composite-sort-keys-for-dynamodb-with-serverless-framework